# How do I test code with randomized Input in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a Yahtzee-style game and I'm in the stage where I've finished coding the ResultCalculator class, which takes the combination of dice and calculates, which results (Large Straight, Yahtzee...) are valid results.

I can't figure out a good way to test it, since the input is randomized. Sure, I could manipulate the Draw class where the dice are rolled so that I can manually set the dies' values but that doesn't seem very straightforward. Any ideas? How are classes like this getting tested in real life?

```
public class Die {
    private Value value;
    private int valueAsInt;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public void rollDie() {
        int result = random.nextInt(1, 7);
        value = switch (result) {
            case 1 -> Value.ONE;
            case 2 -> Value.TWO;
            case 3 -> Value.THREE;
            case 4 -> Value.FOUR;
            case 5 -> Value.FIVE;
            case 6 -> Value.SIX;
        };
        valueAsInt = result;
    }


public class Draw {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_DICE = 5;
    private final Die[] dice = new Die[NUMBER_OF_DICE];
    private final ArrayList<Integer> dieValuesAsInt = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();

 
    private void rollDice() {
        for (Die die : dice) {
            die.rollDie();
        }
    }
```

Then a ResultCalculator is called, it gets handed over Draw.dice & Draw.dieValuesAsInt

Comment: Why would it matter that the _input_ is randomised? Testing things where the _output_ is non-deterministic is tricky, but in the test you control the input.

Comment: Yes, I'd say also that you should design a series of specific tests that show your method(s) are working.  Testing the output is imperative here.  You can also test random inputs, but basically there you're just checking that the code doesn't crash.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i thought it mattered because in uni I was told that we shouldn't modify our code for testing and right now all the methods and fields which I had to access in order to test the class are private.. And I thought it wouldn't be good practice to change that and add a method to manually set the die's values

Comment: So it's the _state_ that's random not the _inputs_? A [mre] would help people understand your actual situation, but refactoring so they _are_ inputs would make it more testable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i added one :)

Comment: Usually the first step is to not use a true random number generator, but a seedable pseudorandom number generator, so you can write deterministic tests.

Comment: _"a ResultCalculator is called, it gets handed over Draw.dice & Draw.dieValuesAsInt"_ - which is just two arrays, so you can pass whatever you want without faking anything. You haven't actually included the thing you want to test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, I think I get it now. I thought I had to manipulate my Code but I can just create my own Array/List. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

### Proper design

Generally 'generate randomness' is one part of a larger scheme. A yahtzee game isn't just one tangled mess that accepts 'play game' in one end, and an entire yahtzee game rolls out at the other end with everything in the middle a black box. If that's how your code works, fix it, that's not a good way to write software. Everything you want to test shouldn't just 'roll up some randomness'. It should work deterministically.

A method should not be, say:

```
public List<ValidPlays> calculatePlays() {
  int[] dice = new int[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) dice[i] = rollDie();

  // calculate valid plays
}
```

Because that's one method conflating two unrelated jobs: The job of rolling dice, and the job of calculating valid plays. There should be only one method that does the random thing, and it will be trivial. It just rolls up n random dice. You can still test it:

```
public int[] rollDice(int amount) {
  int[] out = new int[amount];
  for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) out[i] = rollDie();
  return out;
}
```

you can test this by checking that e.g. `assertEquals(6, rollDice(6).length)`. You can roll 100 times and check that all values are within 1 and 6 (never less than 1, and never more than 6).

And all other methods take in an array of dice, which for test purposes aren't rolled up but are passed in as constants by your test code.

### Seed values

This is more advanced, but if a method's single task inherently involves taking some randomness as part of a larger process, then the above won't work. Imagine a method that takes in a bunch of student course lists (which courses a student is taking) and its job is to shuffle records so that the end result in certain ways looks like a realistic scenario and accurately represents how full each class is, but is anonymous in the sense that the end result cannot be used to determine which classes a student is actually taking.

It's a bit harder to just 'pass in the random' to such a method.

**So, instead, pass in `Random` itself.**

An instance of `Random` is an object you can pass as parameter same as any other object. So, allow that. If you want, you can make an override that takes no arguments and passes in `new Random()` instead.

This way, you can get the same stream of random data every time by making a random object with a constant seed value. Try it!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Random r = new Random(12345L);
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
  System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000));
}
```

Run that app a few times. The exact same sequence of numbers comes out every time.